# Javascript OOP get Children with getElementsByClassName method

Tags: javascript, oop

I have a problem for getting children using `getElementsByClassName` method.

I'm using OOP way just like `Jquery` Does.

```js
"use strict";

var $, i;

(function() {

  $ = function(el) {
    return new obj$(el);
  };

  var obj$ = function(el) {

    var firstChar = el.charAt(0),
        cl        = document.getElementsByClassName(el.slice(1));

    switch (firstChar) {
      case ".":
        for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
          this[i] = cl[i];
        }
        break;

    }

  };

  obj$.prototype = {

    find : function(child) {

      for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        this[i].getElementsByClassName(child)[0];
      }

      return this;

    },
    html : function(data) {

      for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        this[i].innerHTML = data;
      }

      return this;

    }

  };

})();

var x = $(".parent").find("child").html("replace!");
console.log(x);
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  this is parent 1
  <p class="child">test 1</p>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  this is parent 2
  <p class="child">test 2</p>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  this is parent 3
  <p class="child">test 3</p>
</div>
```

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Lng5mn3o/

It doesn't work.

Comment: `this[i].getElementsByClassName(child)[0];` is a no-op statement. You're not doing anything with the result. You'll need to construct and `return` a new instance with the results, instead of returning `this`.

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++)` misses a variable declaration and uses a non-existant property.

Comment: thanks Bergi for commenting, what do you mean no-op statement and missed a variable declaration?

Comment: No-op means that it does nothing, it doesn't change or alter anything, your program had the same result if you omitted it. The missing declaration is a `var` for the `i` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated fiddle for you - https://jsfiddle.net/Lng5mn3o/3/

The main thing what i changed in your `jsfiddle` example, i created `this['elements']` to store matched elements and used it length in loop rest was ok in your code

```
 // define blank array
 this['elements'] = new Array();

 // store elements
 this['elements'][i] = cl[i];

 // loop over that elements     
 for (i = 0; i < this['elements'].length; i++) {
```

Comment: That's not necessarily a mistake. Every object can be array-like.

Comment: @Bergi yes i know but he need to have some separate array with elements as he cant use `this.length` to count matched elements

Comment: Well he could simply set `this.length = …`, although it won't update automatically of course. Given that the `obj$` *should* be immutable though, that wouldn't matter.

Comment: @Armen  thats not correct you can store the elements in `this[i]` and if you keep the `this.length` in sync then you have an array like object. Ths is done by many libs like jQuery.

Comment: finally, after 4 hours, cool! good job Armen. thankkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk you so muchhhhhhhhhhhh!!!  YOU DA REAL MVP!

Comment: Thank you @Bergi and @t.niese for correction, i agree with you there is many many ways to do this also with `this.length`, i have choose'n option with `this['elements']` to provide solution, you can also provide with `this.length` your examples in answers